# How do you ensure you don't create model twice using history in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, routes, backbone.js, history

In my router I have

```
routes: {
    "create/:type": "create",
    // #create/modeltype
    "diagram/:id": "diagram",
    // #diagram/193
    "": "list"
    //
    },
```

then i have the create route

```
    create: function(type) {
        console.log("diagram create " + type.toUpperCase());

        var newDiagram = new Diagram({
            type: type.toUpperCase()
            });

        newDiagram.save({}, {
            success: function(model, response) {
                console.log("save diagram success");
                window.vnb.routers.workspace.navigate("diagram/" + model.get("id"), true);

            },
            error: function(model, response) {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(model);
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    },
```

If someone creates a model and then clicks back, they create another model, i would like this to not happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `newDiagram` variable into a property on the router called `diagram`. Then you can instantiate it the first time the create method is called, and the following calls to the create method can use the variable.

Here's an example

```
create: function(type) {
    console.log("diagram create " + type.toUpperCase());

    if (this.diagram === undefined) {
        this.diagram = new Diagram({
          type: type.toUpperCase()
        });
    }

    this.diagram.save({}, {
        success: function(model, response) {
            console.log("save diagram success");
            window.vnb.routers.workspace.navigate("diagram/" + model.get("id"), true);

        },
        error: function(model, response) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(model);
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

},
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, but its not quite what i want, this means i can never create a new diagram. I just want to remove the create route from the router history stack.